# ¿Para qué sirve el método GetContextPaht() de HTTPServletRequest?

Tags: http, java-ee

Según la documentación dice esto:

> Devuelve la parte de URI de la solicitud que indica el contexto de la solicitud.

Lo que yo he entendido es lo siguiente:

- Sí estoy en **www.unsitio.com/login**  y envío una solicitud con los
  datos de login, `getContextPaht()` me devuelve **/login** que sería
  el contexto.

Podrían darme un ejemplo para entender que es lo que devuelve y sabe que es exactamente el **Contexto**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `getContextPath()` devuelve el **nombre de la aplicación (o directorio raíz del proyecto)** en Java EE.

Aquí un ejemplo.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().append("Esto devuelve el método getContextPath() : \n  ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }
```

En la imagen se ve lo que pasa después de que se ejecuta el método `doGet()` el cual contiene `request.getContextPath()`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El método `doGet()` se ejecuta después de introducir la URL `http://localhost:8080/Ejemplo/ServletEjemplo` en el navegador.

Cómo se puede ver en la siguiente imagen la carpeta **Ejemplo** es el directorio del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]